# IdentityServer4: Generate Refresh Token and ReferenceToken Together

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 to secure my API-s.
I've created client with these parameters:

**AccessTokenType** = 1 //Reference Token
**AllowOfflineAccess** = 1 //Property to allowe refresh Tokens

I'm calling this method to request reference Token and refresh token together:

```
            var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
            {
                Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
                ClientId = ConfigurationExt.IdentityServer.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationExt.IdentityServer.ClientSecret,
                UserName = userName,
                Password = passwordHash,
                Parameters = parameters,
                Scope = ConfigurationExt.IdentityServer.Scope,
            });
```

but I'm getting refreshToken null

Is it possible to get both refresh and reference token ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only get the refresh token if you use the authorization code flow to get the tokens, not using the password grant.

Also, today you should try to only use the authorization code flow or clients credentials flow. All other flows are deprecated if you want to follow OAuth 2.1.